# Why wont my cipher print correctly?

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to write a program that takes an input file password, encrypts it, then saves it to another file while still encrypted. So far I've gotten the program to create the file and for each letter in the password it will replace the letter. The problem is for each letter in the password, I'm printing out the password instead of a character of the alphabet.I want to take my password "fallout" and for each letter change is to a different random letter. Like "fallout" to "dfljsor" for example. I believe the problem is with my print line, how do I fix it?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WriteFile {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        java.io.File inputFile = new java.io.File("inputFile.txt");
        java.io.File outputFile = new java.io.File("encrypted.txt");

        //create files and write to files
        try(Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);  
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outputFile);) {
            //creating array that holds the abc's
            //password is tombraider
            String key[] = { "q","w","r","t","u","i","o",
                             "p","a","s","d","f","g","h",
                             "j","k","l","z","x","c","v",
                             "b","n","m" };
            String key1[] = { "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" };

            while (input.hasNext()) {
                String x = input.nextLine();

                //select a random char in key
                double number = Math.random() * 27;
                String index = key1.toString();
                char sort = index.charAt((int) number);

                // for each letter in the password, it is to be replaced with sort 
                for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
                    char select = ((char) i);
                    output.print(x.replace(select, sort));
                }     
            } 
        }    
    }      
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the desired behaviour is here, but replace returns the new string with the replaced characters. Replace also replaces ALL instances of oldChar with newChar. Check out the documentation

Comment: I want to take my password "fallout" and for each letter change is to a different random letter.Like fallout to dfljsor for example.

Comment: The problem here is that if you do a replace then a single index in your string might be changed several times. Say you change a to b, then b to c. For the string "ab" you will first get "bb", then "cc". The better solution here would be to do as one of the answers pointed out: Iterate over the String, replacing a single character at a time (using for example a hashmap of char-to-char mappings)

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as encryption, because you're producing ciphertext that you can't revert to plaintext only knowing the key. You would also need to know the random index for each line that you chose during encryption.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have high enough rep to comment (which I meant to). But it seems you are using `x.replace(select, sort)`. You have set `x` to an entire line. What you probably intended to do was something like `Character.toString(x.charAt(i)).replace(select, sort))` or of the sort. That way you get each character, instead of the entire line.